# Why doesn't percent height on child elements work when parent has height with calc function?

Tags: html, css

```css
.html, body {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: calc( 100%-100px);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Here I have used height with calc function on container. The problem is that the child div doesn't take 100% height of its parent. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

Need to add spaces with `calc()` function :

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Then, remove the html, body padding :

```
.html, body {
  padding: 0;
}
```

[In this fiddle I've made with the code above](https://jsfiddle.net/to0op1h3/1/), the container is full 100% height of the parent.

[In the fiddle @Frits provided](https://jsfiddle.net/to0op1h3/), he corrected the `calc()` issue.

Comment: I thought white spaces are ignored in css. e.g. in minfied css all blank spaces are deleted.

Comment: I've just done this in a fiddle - feel free to add it to your answer - works perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/to0op1h3/ - good job

Comment: When I use this on my website then it doesn't work. When I resize my website http://sycoscientistrecords.github.io/ the media query for max-width 720 comes into action. But rather giving 100% height it gives nothing to the `.carousel` div

Comment: Seems in that case that you can't use fluid values. With vh or px values, it works fine.

Comment: I found the bug. I had to give 100% height to all elements that come along the nesting order.

Comment: Ok, it's a more proper solution than fixed value

Comment: No it's not better than fixed value because when used on mobile the viewport height changes because of the url bar and that causes a blink-resize effect. Moreover on iphone the content is pushed below the url bar, causing the content to go below the visible region.